# A animated video with effects similar to Valiant Hearts

Tags: animation

I am trying to create a 2-3 minute video with a style similar to the below Valiant Hearts video
(Starts at 1:40.

)

What is that animation called? Is it 2D or 3D? What kind of software is used to make such kind of videos?
As per the feedback from Animation Stack Exchange it uses parallax effects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the software and effect I was looking for.
The Parallax Effect - Adobe After Effects.